# Mongodb Search from Collection

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query

I need to Search collection in mongodb having

`'food_name' => 'fish'`

and

```
  'room_features' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Shower',
    1 => 'Hairdryer',
  ),
```

I tried the following code. But the result is not-correct. I think multiple `$eq` is not allowed (same index in array).

```
array (
  '$and' => 
  array (

    array (
      'food' => 
      array (
        '$elemMatch' => 
        array (
          'food_name' => 
          array (
            '$eq' => 'fish',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),

    array (
      'room' => 
      array (
        '$elemMatch' => 
        array (
          'room_features' => 
          array (
            '$elemMatch' => 
            array (
              '$eq' => 'Shower'
              '$eq' => 'Hairdryer'

            ),
          ),
          'roomrate' => 
          array (
            '$eq' => new MongoInt32(2500),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),


  ),
)
```

Here is the document I need to search.

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("59670aca7fafd8342e3c9869"),
  'subcat_name' => 'Test',
  'place' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'created_date' => '1499970060',
  'created_by' => 'Admin',
  'openingtime' => '',
  'closingtime' => '',
  'hotel_class_id' => '594245f67fafd87e243c986a',
  'hotel_type_id' => '594244177fafd884563c9869',
  'latitude' => '0',
  'longitude' => '0',
  'dist_id' => '5911966a7fafd8c83c3c986a',
  'cat_id' => '58fb230e7fafd883183c986d',
  'featured' => '0',
  'visited' => new MongoInt64(5),
  'subcat_slug' => 'test-trivandrum-1',
  'image' => NULL,
  'food' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'food_id' => '149992634012642164',
      'region_id' => '5944ba947fafd883333c9869',
      'food_name' => 'fish',
      'type' => 'veg',
      'rate' => '100',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'food_id' => '14999366891994980639',
      'region_id' => '595c75c17fafd835173c986c',
      'food_name' => 'curry',
      'type' => 'veg',
      'rate' => '1000',
    ),
  ),
  'room' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'room_id' => '14999346791721342880',
      'roomtype' => 'DELUXE KING ROOM1',
      'roomrate' => new MongoInt64(2500),
      'image' => 'beach_icon33.png',
      'room_features' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Shower',
        1 => 'Hairdryer',
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'room_id' => '14999346901389554873',
      'roomtype' => 'DELUXE KING ROOM new',
      'roomrate' => new MongoInt64(4000),
      'image' => 'beach_icon34.png',
      'room_features' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Shower',
        1 => 'Bathrobe',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Please Give me an alternate way to search multiple item from array.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP Array Notation is generally not a good representation of data for the wider audience. Even the dump format does not usually give an accurate description. Instead you should post your data as it appears when viewed from the "mongo shell". This gives an accurate depiction for a much wider audience to understand. Also when using PHP, it's good to actually include that tag on the question, rather than make people guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to query list you can add the list in query,
try this

```
{
    "food" : {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "food_name" : "fish"
        }
    },
    "room" : {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "room_features" : ["Shower", "Hairdryer"]
        }
    },
}
```

Hope this help.